# Figure out what am I

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I have waves, just not like the sea
>   I'm not rare, but I'm unique
>   Useful sometimes I can be
>   Others in trouble, I can put you in

Added:

> I'm as old as you are, but nowadays more popular.

Comment: This riddle seems fairly broad. I can think of several different answers that I could make to fit all of the lines. Is there any special wordplay in the riddle, should we be trying to hone in on particular phrases or idioms?

Comment: try then, @hexomino, but i can add a hint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> A fingerprint

I have waves, just not like the sea

> A fingerprint is a pattern of ridges in the skin

I'm not rare, but I'm unique

> Everyone has them, but the specific pattern is unique to the individual

Useful sometimes I can be

> They can be useful in identifying a person

Others in trouble, I can put you in

> If you're a criminal, your fingerprints can get you convicted

Comment: Haha. I was 1 minute too late xD

Comment: congratulations!

Comment: You haven't yet catched the added part ;) 
With fingerprint scanning on phones / laptops it has become a popular authentification method ;)

Answer (score 4):

My guess is you are a

> Brain

I have waves, just not like the sea

> A brainwave is an electrical impulse in the brain or a sudden clever idea. Both are certainly different in form from waves in the sea.

I'm not rare, but I'm unique

> Brains are very common things but each individual's brain is unique.

Useful sometimes I can be

> The brain is incredibly useful for communicating, performing difficult tasks and devising new ideas.

Others in trouble, I can put you in

> Of course, your brain is responsible for both good and bad decisions and sometimes can put you in trouble as well, especially if acting impulsively.

Comment: is not, sorry. i will add now a line

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Fingerprints

I have waves, just not like the sea

> They look like waves.

I'm not rare, but I'm unique

> Fingerprints are not rare as they kind of look similar, but each has a unique pattern.

Useful sometimes I can be

> Security applications use fingerprints for authorization to indicate that it is you who is trying to access the object.

Others in trouble, I can put you in

> When you are arrested, they take your fingerprints. When they match suspects for a crime, your fingerprint can put you in trouble.

I'm as old as you are, but nowadays more popular.

> Your fingerprints have the same age you. Nowadays they have more applications in smart phones and other areas.

Comment: yay! congratulations

Comment: I think you should accept Irishpanda's answer. He was 1 minute earlier than me xD

Comment: yeah, was an error heheh

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer -

> sin (x) function .

I have waves, just not like the sea

> Plot sin(x) on graph gives waves.

I'm not rare, but I'm unique

> Sin(x) is used frequently in math , unique as it is a single tone i.e contains only one frequency.

Useful sometimes I can be
Others in trouble, I can put you in

> used for modulation , but math questions may be difficult.

Comment: sorry, is not correct. but is kind of original! :D

Answer (score 2):

You could be

> Gravity

I have waves...

> Gravitational waves were recently confirmed

I'm not rare...

> It's everywhere

Useful...

> Gravity is very useful

Trouble...

> Stay away from black holes

Comment: Unique? Useful? I keep in mind the part about the black holes

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> A hand wave

I have waves, just not like the sea

> Bit self explanitory this one, hand wave isnt the sea

I'm not rare, but I'm unique

> Alot of people wave their hands in greeting or other such things but people wave their hands differently

Useful sometimes I can be

> You can call someone over will a hand wave

Others in trouble, I can put you in

> depending on your country a hand wave/gesture can be seen as [insulting](http://www.expatinfodesk.com/blog/2011/08/02/5-innocent-hand-gestures-that-can-land-you-in-hot-water-overseas/)

Comment: Sorry, also incorrect. Keep trying ^^